# a/the symbiosys between academic and non-academic components. which article?

Tags: articles

I want to write the following sentence:

I have always believed in the wholesome nature of a/the symbiosis between academic and non-academic spheres of life.

I don't know which article to use. I read the following article on Cambridge dictionary blog, but it doesn't say anything that I didn't already know: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/a-an-and-the

Comment: Why did you choose *the* before *wholesome nature*?

Comment: "Nature", with the intended meaning is uncountable, so "the" is unnecessary?

Comment: Sameer, sorry to disappoint you and this is not an ELU question; it's hardly an English Language Learning question.

Your best option would be to form at least three native or at least five secondary speakers of English into a study group and work together to solve such problems.

Please recognise the sophistication of *a/the symbiosys between academic and non-academic components. which article?* is not the point.

The point is the simplicity of *a/the… which article* which for native speakers should have been dealt with before age 10, anyway.